# HTML select <option> returns only the first letter of selected option

Tags: html, html-select

I have a code somewhat like this

```
<?php
    if($_POST['post'] == 'Post')
    {
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];
        $update = "UPDATE table SET category='$cat' WHERE id = '$id' ";
        $result = mysql_query($update) or die ("update error");             
    }
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="cat">
        <option >Arts and Entertainment</option>
        <option >Automotive</option>
        <option >Book Reviews</option>
        <option >Business</option>
        <option >Communications</option>
        <option >Computers and Technology</option>
        <option >Finance</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
</form>
```

I summarized my code for you to get it easily,
whatever I select on my option, 
only the First letter of the option comes out.

Comment: Why don't you use `value` attribute in `<option>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems ok on both PHP and HTML side.
So you might have store your value on `category` with its fieldtype `varchar(1)` or `char(1)`.
If that is the case increase your `char` or `varchar` length to let say 50.